# Cocoa Touch Objective-C: How to invoke the same ViewController twice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iPhone app that loads 5 items on a TabBarController.

When the app loads the first view is an audio player (an instance of **MyAudioPlayerViewController**)

Suppose the user starts to play a song on **MyAudioPlayerViewController** and then decides to tap on the **second Tab Bar Item**, which has 6 options on a **UITableView** to choose from. The user makes a selection, that leads to another UITableView (with some other options to choose from), then they make another selection, leading to a final ViewController, that is an audio player as well.

I need this final UIViewController to be the **SAME** as the first one that had the inicial song playing and **NOT** a new instance of **MyAudioPlayerViewController**.

Why do I need this configuration? I need it because in the very moment that the user makes his final selection on the previous UITableView the song that is playing **MUST STOP**.

This final view having the MyAudioPlayerViewController must be able the access my custom NSObject class that is playing the audio, making it stop the current song.

Right now I have this code that is invoking MyAudioPlayerViewController that shows the final UIViewController:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    MyAudioPlayerViewController * myAudioPlayerViewController = [[MyAudioPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAudioPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myAudioPlayerViewController animated:YES];   
    [myAudioPlayerViewController changeText:[arraySingerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withSong:[arraySongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
    [myAudioPlayerViewController release];    
}
```

As you can see it makes a new instance of MyAudioPlayerViewController, that has nothing to do with the very first one when app launched, then I'm able to invoke the method on my custom NSObject class (the player itself) responsible to stop the previous audio that is playing because it is protected.

Is there any solution for this case or should I build everything again using another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to reference the MyAudioPlayerViewController instance from your other classes. You can do this through your app delegate if you like.

If your tab bar controller is set up using Interface Builder, create an IBOutlet in your app delegate of class MyAudioPlayerViewController and hook it up to your MyAudioPlayerViewController in Interface Builder.

If you're setting up the tab bar controller in code, simply alloc/initialize the instance variable and set it as your first tab.

You'll need to either set its properties or create an accessor method so you can access it from other classes.

To set up the property, open up your app delegate .h file and add this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyAudioPlayerViewController *myAudioPlayerViewController;
```

and in your app delegate .m file add this:

```
@synthesize myAudioPlayerViewController;
```

Then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    YourAppDelegate *yourAppDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    MyAudioPlayerViewController * myAudioPlayerViewController = [yourAppDelegate myAudioPlayerViewController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myAudioPlayerViewController animated:YES];   
    [myAudioPlayerViewController release];    
}
```

For more info about properties in Objective-C: http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas for helping me out, Thomas!!! I'm using the Interface Builder and have created the IBOutlet on my AppDelegate and hooked it up on IB. How do I create the accessor method? I'm getting the warning: Method myAudioPlayerViewController not found...

Comment: @Winston I've added info about creating the property above. It'll create the accessor method for you.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, you're helping me a lot! I've tried that, again I receive the warning saying that the method is not found. I don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: @Winston Added a couple lines to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Replace YourAppDelegate with the appropriate class!

Comment: It works, and now I'm doing some fine tuning with hiding and showing the UITabBar at at bottom. I'll let you know. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 2):

Since they are part of the tab bar controller and say your instance of `MyAudioPlayerViewController` is at the first tab. You can do this,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    MyAudioPlayerViewController * myAudioPlayerViewController = nil;
    for ( UIViewController * viewController in self.tabBarController.viewControllers ) {
        if ( [viewController isMemberOfClass:[MyAudioPlayerViewController class]] ) {
            myAudioPlayerViewController = (MyAudioPlayerViewController *)viewController;
        }
    }

    if ( !myAudioPlayerViewController ) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't retrieve player");
    }

    [myAudioPlayerViewController changeText:[arraySingerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withSong:[arraySongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Here we access the first view controller in the list of view controllers in the tab bar and call `changeText:withSong:` as it is our instance of `MyAudioPlayerViewController`. Then we shift the current tab to point to our music player and later pop to the root view controller in that navigation controller as the next time the user can start afresh. Modify this behavior as you want it.

Comment: I'm trying this out and will let you how things went. Thanks Deepak!

Comment: Since I'm using an UINavigation controller to push the UITableViews, I'm getting [UINavigationController changeText: withSong:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x480620. What should I change?

Comment: Which tab is the audio player in? Was it also pushed into a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: The audio player is in the very first tab. It shows up right after the loading splash screen. It's not pushed from any UINavigationController. I Think that when I go the second Tab and make my two selections on the UITableviews the first tab is nil. Another thing, I'm hiding the TabBar like so: self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; before calling the MyAudioPlayerViewController

Comment: I have modified the code in my answer and check if it logs anything or works :)

Comment: Thanks again! The player shows up, but NSLog gives me: Couldn't retrieve player. I know we're almost there!

Comment: How do you push the player into the tab bar controller - programmatically or via IB? If IB can you post a screenshot of the tab bar controller lay out in the left side bar in IB and if programmatically, some code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need this configuration? I
>   need it because in the very moment
>   that the user makes his final
>   selection on the previous UITableView
>   the song that is playing MUST STOP.

An easy way to do this is to have any objects that play audio post a notification before they start playing, and also observe that same notification coming from any other object. If an audio player gets such a notification, it should stop any sounds that it's currently playing.

This way, you can have as many audio player controllers as you want without them getting in each other's way, but none of them have to know about any of the others.

Comment: I have a notification center setup. I'll think about it. Thanks a lot!